# Unable to Set Cookie Expiration Time on LocalHost

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am writing a cookie and trying to set the expiration time in my localhost. However, it is always showing Ending time as "When browsing session ends"

Here is the code

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;
setcookie('rememberme', $cookie, time()+86400*7, '/', $domain, false);
```

Can someone please help me on why I am facing this issue?

[image]

This is causing my cookie to get destroyed every time I close my browser.

Comment: Try putting hard coded values in instead: setcookie('rememberme', 'a value', time()+86400*7, '/', 'http :// localhost', false);

Comment: “it is always showing Ending time as "When browsing session ends"” – That’s the [definition of a session cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue myself. There was some other issue in my code. Apologies for the inconvenience.